# When the Weighted Sum method yields a unique solution in MOLP?

Tags: convex-optimization, multi-objective-optimization

I would like to ask if there are some specific conditions under which the Weighted Sum method yields a unique solution for MOLP or more general for convex problems. Let us assume that the number of objectives-criteria are more than two.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by unique? Do you mean that $\min \lambda^Tf(x):x\in\mathcal{X}$ has the same optimal solution for all strictly positive weight vectors $\lambda$. Or do you mean if there is a unique optimiser for a specific weight vector?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, of course I mean if there is a unique solution given a specific weighing vector.

Comment: Then the question depends on what type of problem you have. For example, if your weighted objective is strictly convex and your feasible set is convex, then the solution is unique. That is, you should look in the single objective optimisation (as the weighted objective lives in $\mathbb{R}$) literature, for conditions for a unique optimum.

Comment: For a fixed weighting of the objectives, a weighted sum MOLP is just a linear program, so in effect you are looking for specific conditions under which a linear program has a unique solution. I don't think you will find conditions that are less work to evaluate than just solving the problem and finding out.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the replies. As noticed, since a weighted sum MOLP is just a linear program, then multiple optimal solutions may exist. It is problem specific if the optimal solution will be unique or not.